# How to copy and say user's input?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am making a discord bot and currently trying to make the bot repeat what the user says.

```
cService.CreateCommand("say")
                .Parameter("user", ParameterType.Unparsed)
                .Do(async (e) =>
        {
                Message[] CopiedMessage = await e.Channel.DownloadMessages(1);
                await e.Channel.SendMessage(CopiedMessage); //Error, only can print string
        });
```

I am right now having problems trying to print out the `CopiedMessage` as it's datatype is `Message[]` and I have to convert to a string to make the bot say it. I tried converting it to a string using `ToString` but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining your `CopiedMessage` using `string CopiedMessage = e.Args[0];` instead.

`DownloadMessages()` is mainly used for deleting messages on the channel, although it can be used to print out after some complex process. Even if it works , since it is not a string, it will give out a weird string of numbers anyway since you downloaded the message's data, not the message's value.